# Question about Tails Download and Installation

Tags: macos, tail

Simple questions regarding Tails installation for Mac OS. Any guidance is appreciated. 
I have looked over the Tails installation requirements and have watched multiple videos on how to download it to a USB. The two questions which I haven't been able to find an answer for are:

1. For the download portion, before installation, does the ISO image need to be downloaded to the USB? Or simply to the desktop, and then installed on to the USB.
2. Am I able to use my USB that has Tails installed on any public or private computer (Ex: Walk into a public library and plug the USB into any computer)? Or only computers which have Tails downloaded.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to download the ISO to your computer and then install it into the USB with specialized utilities (like https://tails.boum.org/etcher/Etcher.dmg) that will make it a bootable drive. Simply dragging the ISO into the USB won't work.
2. You can use your Tails USB from any computer that supports boot over USB and has the required hardware specs: no need for the computer to download anything. It is safe to assume a computer you don't own or have full access to will probably have USB boot disabled, but there's no way to know beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will checkmark once the timer is up.

Comment: double checked the documentation and Unebootin is not recommended, they use something called "Etcher" now. Answer updated. Check out the instructions: https://tails.boum.org/install/mac/usb/index.it.html